# Lagrange's Theorem (number theory)

Tags: number-theory

I am currently doing a proof of Lagrange's Theorem (and smaller related results) for an assignment. I believe I've almost got it done, but I need that push over the edge.

First, I need to prove that if $f(X)$ is a polynomial of degree *n* modulo N, and $f(a) \equiv 0\pmod N$, then $f(X)\equiv (X-a)g(X\pmod N$, where *g* is a polynomial of degree *n-1* modulo N. I have used the fact that $f(X)\equiv f(X)-f(a)$, and rewriting the part on the right to 
\begin{equation}
(X-a)(a_{n}\frac{X^{n}-a^{n}}{X-a}+a_{n-1}\frac{X^{n}-a^{n}}{X-a}+...+a_{1})
\end{equation}
, using the fact that $(X-a)\mid(X^{n}-a^{n})$. Here's the tough part though: I need to prove that the expression in the second paranthesis is a polynomial of degree *n-1* modulo N. The degree is simple  to verify, as it is a linear combination of polynomials of max grade *n-1*, but I am unsure how to confirm that it is still a polynomial of degree *n-1* modulo N.

Second question: Taking the above result as proven, I now need to prove Lagrange's Theorem, that is, finding the maximum number of incongruent solutions to $f(X)\equiv 0\pmod p$, where *p* is a prime. I am assuming I need to use the property proven above, that a polynomial is congruent with the product $\prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-a_{i})+r$ modulo *p*. However, I am completely blank on how to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

The main trick is the fact that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field, hence $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is an integral domain, and given $q(x)\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ and $a\in\mathbb{F}_p$,
$$ q(a) = 0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad (x-a)\mid q(x) $$
since we have a well-defined polynomial division. The degree function $\partial$ over $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ satisfies:
$$\partial(a(x)\cdot b(x)) = \partial(a(x))+\partial(b(x))$$
hence if $(x-a)\mid q(x)$ and $r(x)=\frac{q(x)}{(x-a)}$, by taking $a(x)=(x-a)$ and $b(x)=r(x)$ in the above formula we have:
$$\partial(r(x)) = \partial(q(x)) -1.$$

Comment: In the course in question, I haven't learned any abstract algebra but the definition of a group. Is there a proof that answers this in only number theory?